# Entity Framework SaveChanges Return Error. AddObject Does not set Primary Key

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have a `Property` table and another is `Detail` table. Where I am using disconnected approach where multiple properties are added and then when we click the save button it will save changes to the database. This approach of not saving for every property added is because user can delete from the list also.

Here's what I am doing

```
foreach (Property P in Results)
{
  if(P.PropertyId==0 && P.EntityState==EntityState.Added)
    Repository.Properties.AddObject(P);
}
```

but when I try to save the data

```
public void Save()
{
  Repository.SaveChanges();
}
```

it returns error

> Unable to determine the principal end of the 'database.FK_Details_Property'
>   relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.

I think its because every time I call AddObject its primary key is 0 and I don't know what could solve this problem. Is this similar or sounds familiar to anyone who has encountered it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you set the the PropertyId to an Auto Generated value?

Comment: Ok just asking, i had forgotten it once. :) You could try to use AdtoTableName method of the repository or specify the table you wanna add the entity to.

Comment: I have also tried that. The Problem in this is there are multiple properties added and then if we try save changes it wont save because everybody will have Id=0; So is there any workaround to hold data with actual primary key or getting rid of this method. I have edited the code. Thanks.

Comment: No i dont have any circular dependency

Comment: Please add the code where you save Detail entity and the order you do the code with multiple property save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)You may want to check about a circular dependency. It may be between the two entities Save Product with detail entities or viceversa

Check here : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sk/adodotnetentityframework/thread/5ba666ff-0103-4a83-b4d0-743c16a99491

2)Be careful when you add Repository.Properties.AddObject(P); because in the code behind the P entity still has a reference to Detail table.

Make sure the detail related entity doesn't already save the objects that are linked to it.

If the Detail object has 3 properties , when you save Detail you will also save the 3 properties.

Answer (score 2):

its definitely identity column related here.

Assuming your using MS SQL 
please check that on table your are inserting and any related ones
that the

1) Identity Specification = YES

2) Is Identity = YES

3) Identity Increment = 1

4) Identity Seed = 1

Its definitely trying to insert the PK for you, so you need to look around there. Make sure you check child tables also.
If you still have problems and your not using the code first method, try regenerate these tables in your EDMX also.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this code in your code:

```
foreach (Property P in Results)
{
  if(P.PropertyId==0 && P.EntityState==EntityState.Added)
  {
    var id = Repository.Properties.Max(p => (int?)p.PropertyId) ?? 0;
    P.PropertyId=++id;
    Repository.Properties.AddObject(P);
    Repository.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

of course in the first line of file add:

```
using System.Linq;
```

for used in multi threading:

```
foreach (Property P in Results)
{
  if(P.PropertyId==0 && P.EntityState==EntityState.Added)
  {
       while(true){
         try{
            var id = Repository.Properties.Max(p => (int?)p.PropertyId) ?? 0;
            P.PropertyId=++id;
            Repository.Properties.AddObject(P);
            Repository.SaveChanges();
            break;
         }catch{
              continue;
         }
       }
  }
}
```

of course better first you creat new instance of 'property' object then assign field by field varible then call AddObject and SaveChanged!

Answer (score 0):

Guid's are good for allowing you to create unique id without a database.

if your using int you will need to ensure that you have in the edmx model to be "Store Generated" for your primary key column.